# Tkinter does not wait for button press, any ideas?

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, for-loop, tkinter

The problem occurs in the line of dictee(). Instead of waiting for an entry and button press, it continues until all WORDS items have passed. I found solutions with "var" but I don't understand how to implement this, because 'command' already has a callback to check(). Any suggestions?

`tk.Button(window, text="Check", width=6, command=lambda: check(ANSWER,WORD)) .grid(row=3, column=0)`

```py
#import necessary
import tkinter as tk
import sys, random, time, json

#setup window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Aliyah's vocabulary game")
window.configure(background = "black")

#my photo
photo1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="dictee.gif")
tk.Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0)

def main():
    #setting up the game
    global WORDS_CORRECT, WORDS_WRONG, WORDS
    WORDS_CORRECT = 0
    WORDS_WRONG = 0
    with open('vocabulary.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        WORDS = data["words"]
    for widget in window.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    tk.Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0)
    tk.Label (window, text = "Do you want to start?", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=1)
    tk.Button(window, text="Yes", width=6, command=lambda: dictee(WORDS)) .grid(row=2, column=0)
    tk.Button(window, text="No", width=6, command=sys.exit) .grid(row=2, column=1)
    tk.Button(window, text="Manage list", width=10, command=manage_list) .grid(row=3, column=1)

def dictee(WORDS):
    #Show random words and ask for input.
    if WORDS == []:
        for widget in window.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        tk.Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label (window, text = "this were all words.", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Label (window, text = "correct words: %d" % WORDS_CORRECT, bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=2, column=0)
        tk.Label (window, text = "wrong words: %d" % WORDS_WRONG, bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=3, column=0)
        tk.Label (window, text = "Do you want to try it again?", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=0)
        tk.Button(window, text="yes", width=6, command=main) .grid(row=5, column=0)
        tk.Button(window, text="no", width=6, command=exit_game) .grid(row=5, column=1)
        window.update()
    else:
        random.shuffle(WORDS)
        for WORD in WORDS:
            for widget in window.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()
            tk.Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0)
            word = tk.Label (window, text = WORD, bg="black", fg="white", font="none 20 bold")
            word.grid(row=1, column=0)
            window.update()
            window.after(3000)
            word['text'] = ''
            window.update()
            ANSWER = tk.Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
            ANSWER.grid(row=2, column=0)
            tk.Button(window, text="Check", width=6, command=lambda: check(ANSWER,WORD)) .grid(row=3, column=0)
            WORDS.remove(WORD)

def check(ANSWER, WORD):
    #Cross check word shown with answer given
    global WORDS_CORRECT, WORDS_WRONG
    if ANSWER.get() == WORD:
        tk.Label (window, text = "Wat goed!", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=0)
        WORDS_CORRECT += 1
    else:
        tk.Label (window, text = "next time better!", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=0)
        WORDS_WRONG += 1

    tk.Label (window, text = "Do you want to try it again", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=5, column=0)
    tk.Button(window, text="yes", width=6, command=lambda: dictee(WORDS)) .grid(row=6, column=0)
    tk.Button(window, text="no", width=6, command=exit_game) .grid(row=6, column=1)

def exit_game():
    '''summarize results and exit after pushing enter'''
    for widget in window.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    tk.Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0)
    tk.Label (window, text = "see you later!", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=1, column=0)
    tk.Label (window, text = "correct words: %d" % WORDS_CORRECT, bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=2, column=0)
    tk.Label (window, text = "wrong words: %d" % WORDS_WRONG, bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=3, column=0)
    tk.Label (window, text = "click on OK to quit", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=0)
    tk.Button(window, text="OK", width=6, command=sys.exit) .grid(row=5, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

window.mainloop()
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque thanks :-) I just started learning python from a book a few weeks ago. I think I updated it correctly.

Comment: Again, an English version would be much easier while trying to code out. Also do you realize that there is no `main()` in the second example, and yet you call it at `if` block

Comment: @CoolCloud thanks, I edited the question. Question though.. why is it important to have the content in English? I mean, the code is English, and it shows what it does? You have to understand that I'm new to coding and also new to asking questions about it :-)

Comment: I guess you should consider not removing from what you are iterating with. ```...for WORD in WORDS...blah blah blah... WORDS.remove(WORD);``` Unless you understand the underlying structure and algorithms for iteration.

Comment: @D.Sikilai If I don't remove WORD, the loop will continue forever. When all WORD is removed from WORDS it stops and asks if you want to go again check() if WORDS ==[]. But this is a noob solution, if you have others I'm all ears. But alson: why is the code without tkinter working? Isn't it basically the same?

Comment: I see your logic of adding the remove, but if that is what its for then it is misplaced. python has an internal mechanism of terminating your loop. Either it first read the size, cached it,then reusing it to determine iteration's end. if size changes on the way there will be no way to know if it is at the end. especially when the internal mechanism uses ```size!=index``` not ```index<size``` or a synonym of the same.

Comment: @D.Sikilai That may be, but without WORDS.remove(WORD) it's not working in the top version of the code (the one without tkinter). Also, do you have a suggestions why the code with tkinter is not working? I think I basically wrote the same. Thanks.

Comment: For that there is a possibility of unneeded recursion ```dictee``` -> ```check``` -> ```dictee```. Note recursion should return, and if it does the caller continues from where they left. Mystery indeed.

Comment: @D.Sikilai I have pinpointed the problem with bit of a noob solution :-) I put a input command after each step. Apparently it does not stop and wait for input after creating an Entry window, the loop just continues. Any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 0):

There was actually no for-loop needed. check() already sends it back to dictee(). Removed the for-loop and wrote WORD = WORDS[0] instead. A bit of a noob-solution, but it does the job. Since WORDS is being shuffled, there is always a different WORD in this position.